# Given $f(x)=ax^6+3x^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+8$, determine the values of $a,c,d,e,f$ and $k$.

Tags: polynomials

I’ve tried a combination of different things but still haven’t found a viable path. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full question (title does not allow that many characters)

Given $f(x)=ax^6+3x^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+8$, determine the values of $a,c,d,e,f$ and $k$ given the following information: $F(x)$ is an EVEN polynomial function that produces a remainder of $19$ when divided by $(x-1)$& $(x^2+2x-24)(x+17)=x^2(x+k)+dx+f$.

Comment: well, $c=e=0,$  the extra bit at the end calculates $d,$   finally $f(1)=19$ says what $a$ is.

Comment: What is $F(x)$? An anti-derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: @peterwhy i think so !